# Android GradientDrawable setColor does not work

Tags: java, android, swing, colors

I have an annoying problem setting a color to a layout in Android;

This is how it looks my element in layout.xml (FrameLayout (painted element) in a LinearLayout ):

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/farPD_mid_linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <!--  top margin layout-->
        <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/farPD_top_margin"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@android:color/white">
        </FrameLayout>
```

I want to **paint** the **FrameLayout** in **white** and I do something like this in Java:

```
    GradientDrawable gd3 = new GradientDrawable();
    gd3.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    FrameLayout topBorder = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.farPD_top_margin);
    topBorder.setBackground(gd3);
```

I also tried with setColors(). Alpha is 255. The problem is that it doesn't paint in WHITE! it paints in some sort of grey :|.(*and nor it's the color set in layout). Plus, if i comment the Java code, and let only the color set in the layout, which is also white, I get the same output: FrameLayout painted in GREY!

Can someone help me please? Thank you!

Comment: What you want to do? be specific

Comment: I want to set the background color of a layout element. In my case I want to set the color "WHITE" to the FrameLayout's background. The FrameLayout is in a LinearLayout as shown above. After calling the Java code, the FrameLayout is painted in grey and not in white. How cand I be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% related to this question, but I thought I'd post what I found out for anybody out there still struggling. I was just having an issue with the `setColors` function of `GradientDrawable` and I stumbled upon this question hoping to find help. As you said, it wouldn't take the colors that I was giving it and would choose something intermediate. In my scenario, I have a list of `Cards` in a `RecyclerView`, and I'm assigning a different gradient color to the background of each. But it always seems as if the color of one `Card` would propagate to the other `Cards` for some reason.

#### Solution

After struggling with it for a bit, I ended taking a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable#setColors%28kotlin.IntArray%29) (which I probably should have done first) and found out you may need to call [`.mutate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable#mutate%28%29) on any instance of `GradientDrawable` before making any changes to it. That's because, unless you specify that the instance is mutable, it may be linked to other existing `GradientDrawable` instances and the changes made to one may propagate to the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set gradient background using xml

gradient_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/selected_blue_color"
                android:endColor="@color/default_blue_color"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

layout.xml

```
LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/farPD_mid_linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <!--  top margin layout-->
        <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/farPD_top_margin"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg">
        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just try to set white image as background for your framelayout